# Laravel 4 - getting 500 Error when uploading large dimension image

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, image-uploading

When I am uploading large dimension photo (5625 * 5000 and size is 2MB) I got 500 error and if I reduce the dimension of this image then it uploads successfully..why is it happening? I am on GoDaddy server. please guide me through this.

```
My PHP.ini settings

max_execution_time = 1000
max_input_time = 1000
memory_limit = 500M
post_max_size = 1000M
upload_max_filesize = 1000M
```

Okay and I have troubleshooted the problem.. When I create a thumb it shows error, but when I remove that code it saves the image

**My code to create thumb**

anybody can explain why is it happening.. and how to get rid of it.

```
$img = Image::make($path.$name);
```

Comment: You mentioned a 500 error; what was in the error log?

Comment: nothing in error log :/

Comment: If you can, check your `display_errors` setting in your php.ini file (it should be set to On).

Comment: it is on already.. and error log is showing last erros of 24 oct.. I have also pasted error_reporting(E_ALL);  at the top of my controller.. but still, no error comes up

Comment: Well, in that case, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52997133/edit) your question to add in the controller that's being problematic. Just as a warning though, if nothing really jumps out from there, then this might not be really answerable.

Comment: okay i have troubleshooted the problem.. when I try to create a thumb it shows error.. and if i remove that code.. it saves the image..

Comment: my code to creaye thumb $img = Image::make($path.$name);

Comment: As a bit of debug, can you add `phpinfo()` to that call (if you can) just to verify that the memory_limit you're configuring is getting respected? I'm honestly really surprised that GoDaddy Hosting would allow half a gig of memory

Comment: here it is : memory_limit 128M (local) 32M(master)

Comment: Alright, so 128M is the hard limit that GoDaddy applies then, and according to http://www.dotsamazing.com/en/labs/phpmemorylimit and entering 5625x5000 and 180x160, you're looking at needing 145MB. So...short answer, it looks like you'll either need to restrict the size of images you can upload (perhaps try 4500x4000) or you'll need to change hosting providers

Comment: could I increase this size in php.ini? it is already 500M .. then why is showing less?

Comment: You can't; it sounds like they have a hard limit, so while they'll display what you entered in, it'll restrict it on the server level. From their perspective, if every single hosted account they had on a shared server claimed 500MB of memory, then they'd have to quadruple their servers to keep up (which in turn means more maintenance and more costs, which would then get passed on to their customers).